# Error : Property [uploads] does not exist on this collection instance - one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to make a one to many relationship between my Users table and my Uploads table.

To do so I did the following :

Added this function to my `User` table :

```
public function uploads(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Upload');
    }
```

And this to my `Upload` table :

```
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

Then I added this simple function to my UploadController :

```
   public function uploads()
{  
    $user_id = auth()->user('id');
    $user = User::find($user_id);
    return view('uploads')->with('uploads',$user->uploads);
}
```

My Uploads view is looking like this :

```
 @extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <h1>Uploads</h1>
    @if(count($uploads)>0)
@foreach($uploads as $upload)
    <div class="well">
        <h3><a href="/uploads/{{$upload->id}}">{{$upload->name}}</a> </h3>
        <small>Written on {{$upload->created_at}}</small>

    </div>
        @endforeach
             {{$uploads->links()}}
    @else
    <p>No uploads found</p>
    @endif

@endsection
```

When I try to go to `myproject.dev/uploads` I'm getting the following error :

> Property [uploads] does not exist on this collection instance.

Since I am new to laravel, as far as I am aware I don't have to run a migration after I make something like this. But still it doesn't work and I just don't see what am I doing wrong? I just followed the documentation....

Comment: add $user->load('uploads'); before return

Comment: 1. you have both sides of relationship defined as `->belongsTo(..)`. One is belongsTo, other side should be `->hasMany(..)`. So in your user model you should define `->hasMany(uploadModel)`. 2. (not too important) you're executing user query 1 time more than necessary. Call `$uploads = auth()->user()->uploads;` to avoid fetching user 1 additional time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in the relationship of the `User` model, it should be like this :

```
public function uploads(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Upload');
}
```

Then you have to eager load the uploads :

```
$user = User::with('uploads')->find($user_id);
```

But the better solution in your case is to load the uploads instead of the user, because you ar using pagination so:

```
public function uploads()
{  
    $user_id = auth()->user('id');
    $uploads = Upload::whereHas('user', function ($query) use($user_id) {
                        $query->where('id', $user_id);
                    })
                    ->paginate(10);
    return view('uploads')->with('uploads',$uploads);
}
```

Ps : you can change 10 in paginate function to metion the needed elements per page.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I tried your modified version of the uploads function, but i got : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'uploads.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `uploads` where exists (select * from `users` where `uploads`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `id` = {"id":2,"name":"John Smith II","email":"lbk@eml.dk","created_at":"2017-12-07 14:10:00","updated_at":"2017-12-07 14:10:00"}))

Comment: Since you're using pagination, the better solution would be to query Uploads directly, by user_id. Something like `Upload::where('user_id', $user->id)->...->paginate()`. But first of all correct your relationship

Comment: @user8900160 Ok, what is the foreign key of the user table in the uploads table ??

Comment: @Maraboc it is user_id

Comment: @user8900160 I don't think so because laravel say the opposite :p => `Unknown column 'uploads.user_id'` !! did you refreshed the database ?

Comment: honestly, before you asked me for the foreign key name I didn't have a foreign key. But I added the foreign key now and it's called user_id. Now when I try to use your method I don't get error, but I am also not getting any records displayed on the page. And I changed the foreign key to point to the different users

Comment: Ahhaa, it's ok :), yes afcourse you will not get any records, you have to refresh the database first with `php artisan migrate:refresh` then create new records because all the data in the database will be removed and you will get what you want :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160728/discussion-between-maraboc-and-user8900160).

Answer (score 0):

You need to eager load `User` model `uploads`. To do so just add this in your Eloquent query:

```
$user = User::whereId($user_id)->with('uploads')->first();
```

And also in your `User` model, you have an error in eloquent relationship. You need to say that this `User` has many `uploads` and `upload` belongs to `User`.

```
public function uploads() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Upload::class)
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I tried it and i got the following error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: No you don't. How he's calling it is fine. Eager loading is neccessary to avoid `n+1` problem, which he doesn't have here.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I have found the error in your relations

Comment: Hey, I tried your propose solution, but I got this error: Trying to get property of non-object